# Get-Command Changing Drive

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, scripting, database

I wrote a powershell script that includes a check for the `invoke-sqlcmd` cmdlet.  Script runs fine under Windows Server 2016.  On 2012 R2, the script fails with:

`Add-Content : Cannot use interface...`

errors when trying to create and write to a log file.

What I discovered is that on Windows Server 2012 R2, when the `Get-Command invoke-sqlcmd` command is run, it changes my drive to `PS SQLSERVER:\>` instead of `PS C:\>`.  This is apparently causing my `create` and `update` log file sections to fail.

Any idea why `Get-Command` would change the drive when checking for a SQL cmdlet, and suggestions to change it back or prevent it in the first place?  I know I could throw a `c:` in the script, but that seems too simple a solution and might have to do it after every DB call.

Comment: Found an answer on stackoverflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273440/why-working-directory-is-changing-when-executing-invoke-sqlcmd

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer over on StackOverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273440/why-working-directory-is-changing-when-executing-invoke-sqlcmd

Apparently, on Windows Server 2012 R2, doing anything with a sql cmdlet preps the environment to run in `PS SQLSERVER:\>`.  Following the suggestion in the above link, I wrapped my sql cmdlets with `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location`.  This seems to resolve my issue.